# Why is login function in code not called?

Tags: javascript

I added a breakpoint at login function. When I submit the form, the login function should be called; but it's not called. And when I log in, the page doesn't redirect to `window.location`. I want the page to be redirected if the login credentials are the same as the one in local storage. I know we shouldn't validate your code client side. But for now, let's just ignore that.

```js
 var db = window.localStorage;

    function signUp() {
        var signupFormDt = document.querySelector('#signup-form');
        var email = signupFormDt.querySelector('input[name="email"]');
        var password = signupFormDt.querySelector('input[name="password"]');
        var userName = signupFormDt.querySelector('input[name="name"]');

        db.setItem(userName.name, userName.value);
        db.setItem(email.name, email.value);
        db.setItem(password.name, password.value);
    }

    function login() {
        var loginFormDt = document.querySelector('#login-form');
        var logEmail = loginFormDt.querySelector('input[type="email"]');
        var logPass = loginFormDt.querySelector('input[type="password"]');
        if (db.email == logEmail.value && db.password == logPass.value) {
            window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
        } else {
            window.location = "http://www.google.com";
        }

    }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <!--Link to StyleSheet-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <h1>
                    <a href="#"></a>
                </h1>
                <nav>
                    <ul class="clearfix">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <h4>Home</h4>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="../html/about.html">
                                <h4>About</h4>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <h4>Contact</h4>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <h4 id="social">Social</h4>
                                <div class="arrow"></div>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Twitter</li>
                                    <li>Facebook</li>
                                    <li>Instagram</li>
                                    <li>Snapchat</li>
                                    <li>Tumblr</li>
                                </ul>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- end of ul of main nav-->
                </nav>
                <!--end of nav-->
            </div>
            <!--end of container-->
        </header>
        <main>
            <section>
                <h3>login Page</h3>
                <div id="login">
                    <p><a href="../html/index.html" title="link to home page">Myselfie Tech</a></p>
                    <form method="Post" id="login-form">
                        <p>
                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email" required>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password" required>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <button type="submit" onsubmit="login()">Submit Query</button>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <button onclick="window.location='../html/index.html'">Back</button>
                        </p>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </section>
        </main>
        <footer>
            <p>
                <center><small>©Copyright 2017 programmers inc.</small></center>
            </p>
        </footer>
        <!--Link to Javascript-->
        <script src="../javascript/scripts1.js"></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

A `button` element does not have an `onsubmit` attribute. You should put that attribute on the `form` tag for it to work. Also make sure that the form submission is cancelled, since you want to control the navigation differently, with `window.location`:

1. Add `return`:

   ```
   <form onsubmit="return login();">
   ```
2. Add `return false`, and `.href` after `location`:

   ```
   function login() {
       var loginFormDt = document.querySelector('#login-form');
       var logEmail = loginFormDt.querySelector('input[type="email"]');
       var logPass = loginFormDt.querySelector('input[type="password"]');
       if (db.email == logEmail.value && db.password == logPass.value) {
           window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
       } else {
           window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
       }
       return false; // <------
   }
   ```

Comment: Also, explicitly return false in that login handler to make it clear you want to cancel the default submit behavior.

Comment: Now its calling the function but not redirecting to window.location

Comment: OK, I added some more suggestions, since you seem not interested in submitting the form (so why `method = "post"`?), but only to relocate.

Answer (score 0):

Try using input tag instead of button for submit

something like

```
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Submit Query" onclick="login()" />
```

Comment: but i want to submit the data as well

Comment: @Icode You can do that using AJAX as well since you have validation logic before posting the data